# DatabaseError: database disk image is malformed sqlite3

Tags: python, database, process, sqlite, multiprocessing

I have running proxy server that filter the domains the client requests for.
The proxy server filter those requests by sqlite local database that contains domains, for every request the client made, the proxy query the database.

After some queries, I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./proxy.py", line 582, in run
    self._process()
  File "./proxy.py", line 567, in _process
    if self._process_rlist(r):
  File "./proxy.py", line 535, in _process_rlist
    self._process_request(data)
  File "./proxy.py", line 426, in _process_request
    checking_url = DOMAINFILTER.SearchAll(site)  # DOMAINFILTER is the class that uses the database
  File "/root/PROXY/filterDomain.py", line 203, in SearchAll
    results_db = self.__local_db.find(url) # local_db is attribute of DOMAINFILTER and handles the connection to the database
  File "/root/PROXY/filterDomain.py", line 67, in find
    self.__cursor.execute(self.__statements["find_phish"], (url,)) # cursor is attribute of DOMAINFILTER and handles the cursor of the database
DatabaseError: database disk image is malformed
```

BTW for every request, the proxy make new process and after it finished, the process dies.

NOTE: `self.__statements["find_phish"]` contains `r"SELECT site FROM phishTBL WHERE url=?;"`

Comment: Are you doing anything to the database other than opening and using it through the SQLite API? Have you disabled synchronization at all?

Comment: I'm only update the database once the proxy is up by insert all the domains, but after that I close the connection and open it again.
Maybe it because it queries the database in every process?

Comment: SQLite should correctly handle concurrent access to the database, unless you've explicitly disabled synchronization. You may want to give [How to Corrupt an SQLite Database File](http://www.sqlite.org/howtocorrupt.html) a read, and see if any of those apply to you.

Comment: I think that all the process that created from the proxy and uses the database made this. [like mention in 1.0 in the above link]
How can I be sure that this is the problem? and if it is, how can I handle it in a way that every request made by the client will be filtered by each process that shows up, without corrupting the DB?